# Почему список List<> добавляется в базу данных не корректно?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server, asp.net-core

Есть такая модель:

```
public class School
{
    public School()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Есть контекст бд:

```
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
}
```

При сборке проекта создаётся база данных и её таблицы. Я ожидал увидеть в этой бд только одну таблицу `Schools`, но я вижу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Появились "лишние" таблицы.

А столбцы у таблицы `Schools` приняли такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит конструктор таблицы `Students`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему список `School.Students` и `School.Teachers` были выведены в отдельные таблицы? Можно ли это как-то исправить?

---

И вот ещё вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял: эта строка обозначает, что столбец `SchoolId` является ссылкой на `School.Id` в таблице `Schools`. Так ли это?

Я ожидал увидеть такую таблицу `Schools`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой вид ты ожидал увидеть?

Comment: Попробуй в редакторе сделать таблицу School так, как ты хотел чтобы она выглядела и добавь этот пример в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Comment: а ты знаешь, что типы в c# отличаются от типов в SQL?

Comment: @Grundy, уже понял. А вы не знаете как тогда добавляют списки?

Comment: что ты сейчас понимаешь под "списками".  Посмотри какие типы данных есть в sql и выбери тот, который ты бы хотел видеть, вместо таблицы.

Comment: @Grundy, список `List<Teacher> Teachers`, например.

Comment: да и типа данных похожего на `List<>` нет (в SQL)

Comment: "как тогда добавляют списки?" - как показано в начале вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что именно так отображение сущностей на БД и задумывалось. Иными словами, отображение списка совершенно корректное, а некорректными являются ваши представления о том как оно должно выглядеть.

Сделано это по двум причинам.

Первая - в большинстве СУБД типа данных "список" попросту нет, и сделать по-другому просто невозможно.

Вторая - в такой реализации вы можете редактировать каждого учащегося и учителя независимо от школы.

Скорее всего, текущая структура вас устроит как только вы поймете как с ней работать. Если же вам по какой-то причине нужно что-то другое - попробуйте следующее:

1. Можно объявить классы Teacher и Student как [Owned Entity Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), в таком случае им не потребуются свои Id и их нельзя будет редактировать отдельно от школы (но они все равно останутся в отдельных таблицах)
2. Можно сериализовать сложную структуру данных в XML или JSON, и положить в БД одним куском (но это лишит вас возможности нормального поиска по сериализованным объектам)
3. Можно выкинуть Entity Framework и перейти на документ-ориентированные СУБД, вроде MongoDB. Или можно перейти на Postgres, где есть типы данных "список" и "вложенная таблица" (но выкинуть Entity Framework для работы с ними придется всё равно).